# Updating user info but does not update and has no error

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to update multiple user info but it won't update. I have tried a lot of ways and all of them would execute, but they do not update the data, and yet throw no errors. Am I missing something?

Here is the code:

```
protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        using (var sqlStt = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
        {
            sqlStt.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlStt.CommandText = "UPDATE USERS SET LAST_NAME = @LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME = @FIRST_NAME, BIRTHDATE = @BIRTHDATE, PHONE_NUM = @PHONE_NUM, EMAIL = @EMAIL WHERE USERNAME ='" + Session["USERNAME"] + "' ";

            sqlStt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LAST_NAME", Lname.Text);
            sqlStt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_NAME", Fname.Text);
            sqlStt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BIRTHDATE", Birthdate.Text);
            sqlStt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHONE_NUM", Phone_num.Text);
            sqlStt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", Email.Text);

            sqlStt.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        sqlCon.Close();

        Display_Info();
        Disable_Field();
        Notificationtext.Text = "Your account has been updated!";
    }
}

void Disable_Field()
{
    Lname.Enabled = false;
    Fname.Enabled = false;
    Birthdate.Enabled = false;
    Phone_num.Enabled = false;
    Email.Enabled = false;
}

void Display_Info()
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, BIRTHDATE, PHONE_NUM, EMAIL FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME ='" + Session["USERNAME"] + "' ", sqlCon);

        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Lname.Text = reader["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
            Fname.Text = reader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
            Birthdate.Text = reader["BIRTHDATE"].ToString();
            Phone_num.Text = reader["PHONE_NUM"].ToString();
            Email.Text = reader["EMAIL"].ToString();
        }

        sqlCon.Close();
    }
}
```

I also wanted to display the update to the textbox then disable it. After I click update, the data before it was updated would display instead.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: You're already using parameters for the `UPDATE`  statement - **WHY NOT** for the `WHERE` clause?!?!?!? It should **REALLY** be `WHERE USERNAME = @UserName` :...... same goes for your `SELECT` in `Display_Info` - use **PARAMETERS** always and everywhere - no exception!

Comment: Check the return value from `ExecuteNonQuery();`. 0 means nothing was updated (and then you should check the Session["username"]. And make it a parameter) Also verify that database is not running `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = ON`

Comment: How exactly do you know that the row is not updated? Does your connection string use the **|DataDirectory|** substitution string?